Can't list printers unless root is in SystemGroup
I'm trying to set up a cups server using a container. The image setup is simple:
FROM docker.io/alpine:3.18

RUN apk add --update --no-cache cups cups-client cups-filters
...

I created a print user and added it to the lp and lpadmin groups.
I then set the SystemGroup directive in /etc/cups/cups-files.conf:
SystemGroup lpadmin

But I always get this when calling lpinfo -v:
/ $ lpinfo -v
lpinfo: Forbidden

Even as the root user.
The logs at /var/log/cups/error_log say this every time I run the lpinfo -v command:
E [10/Aug/2024:05:39:39 +0000] [Client 20] Returning HTTP Forbidden for CUPS-Get-Devices (no URI) from localhost

The only way to make it work is by adding root to the SystemGroup directive:
SystemGroup lpadmin root

/ $ lpinfo -v
network beh
file cups-brf:/
network https
network http
network ipps
network ipp
network lpd
network socket
/ $

If I only have root in there it will ask for a password but also fail:
SystemGroup root

/ $ lpinfo -v
Password for print on localhost?  *****
lpinfo: Forbidden

What's weird is that the print user is NOT even in the root group at all:
/ $ id
uid=1000(print) gid=1000(print) groups=7(lp),102(lpadmin),1000(print)

What's going on here? Is this a bug?
